# netty-tcnative unavailable with Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: tomcat, google-cloud-platform, netty, google-cloud-vision

To start, I'm quite inexperienced with APIs in general. I'm trying to do a simple Java app that calls the Google Cloud Vision Api but I keep running into the same issue that I can't really find any information on whatsoever.

I've cloned down [this repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/vision/cloud-client) with code samples straight from Google. I've built the project using `mvn clean package` and it all works fine. However, when I'm to try it (using the exact commands stated in the README), it doesn't work at all.

First I get an `INFO` message in the log stating:

`netty-tcnative unavailable (this may be normal)`

After that follows:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty_tcnative_windows_x86_32, netty_tcnative_x86_32, netty_tcnative]
```

This error message really doesn't make any sense to me at all. I haven't done anything with netty whatsoever, neither have I been instructed to do anything with it (install dependencies or so).

I got my environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` pointing to my JSON with my API credentials inside it. I really don't know what to do here, extremely thankful for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing this problem as [GRCP Support Platform](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/README.md#supported-platforms)

For clients that use gRPC, the supported platforms are constrained by the platforms that Forked Tomcat Native supports, which for architectures means **only x86_64**, and for operating systems means Mac OS X, Windows, and Linux. Additionally, gRPC constrains the use of platforms with threading restrictions.

if I look at netty_tcnative library in my project. It doesn't have x86_32 library.

[image]

Problem is ==> GRCP not support windows x86 32 bit

My solution is turn old laptop to new laptop with x86_64 :D